# PostgreSQL ambiguous error

Tags: postgresql

```
WITH novos_valores (cd_cidade, nm_cidade, uf) AS (values (12000, 'FAKE CITY', 'RS')),

          upsert AS ( UPDATE cidade cid 
                             SET nm_cidade = nv.nm_cidade, uf = nv.uf
                FROM novos_valores nv
                   WHERE cid.cd_cidade = nv.cd_cidade RETURNING * )

             INSERT INTO cidade (cd_cidade, nm_cidade, uf)
             SELECT cd_cidade, nm_cidade, uf
               FROM novos_valores
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert WHERE upsert.cd_cidade = novos_valores.cd_cidade)
```

This query above is returning the error below, but I just can't see where is it, can anyone help me?

> SQL Error:
>
> ERROR:  column reference "cd_cidade" is ambiguous LINE 11: ...
>   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert WHERE upsert.cd_...
>                                                                 ^

In the block:

```
WITH novos_valores (cd_cidade, nm_cidade, uf) AS (values (12000, 'FAKE CITY', 'RS')),

          upsert AS ( UPDATE cidade cid 
                             SET nm_cidade = nv.nm_cidade, uf = nv.uf
                FROM novos_valores nv
                   WHERE cid.cd_cidade = nv.cd_cidade RETURNING * )

             INSERT INTO cidade (cd_cidade, nm_cidade, uf)
             SELECT cd_cidade, nm_cidade, uf
               FROM novos_valores
              WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM upsert WHERE upsert.cd_cidade = novos_valores.cd_cidade)

Execution time: 3.045 ms
```

Comment: Check: `UPDATE  cid 
                             SET nm_cidade = nv.nm_cidade, uf = nv.uf
                FROM novos_valores nv
                JOIN cidade cid USING(cd_cidade)
                    RETURNING *`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the error is here:

```
UPDATE cidade cid 
SET nm_cidade = nv.nm_cidade, uf = nv.uf
FROM novos_valores nv
WHERE cid.cd_cidade = nv.cd_cidade RETURNING *
```

RETURNING * returns all values from both `cidade` and `novos_valores` tables.
Because both have `cd_cidade` column, there are two columns with the same name in the result, and this column is ambiguous.
You can check how it works in this SQLFiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7cdd3/2

This update:

```
UPDATE cidade cid 
SET nm_cidade = nv.nm_cidade
FROM novos_valores nv
WHERE cid.cd_cidade = nv.cd_cidade 
RETURNING *
```

returns this result:

```
| cd_cidade | nm_cidade | cd_cidade | nm_cidade |
|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|         1 |        22 |         1 |        22 |
```

the result contains two `cd_cidade` columns.
Use `RETURNING cid.*` or `RETURNING nv.*` instead of `RETURNING *`, 
or list explicitely columns you want to get in the result, for example:
 `RETURNING cid.cd_cidade, nv.nm_cidade, cid.uf`